# Recycling in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

When filling an array with values from a shorter array in R, R will "recycle" the elements in the shorter array.  For example, setting an array of length 7 `[ , , , , , , ]` with the array `['a','b','c']` will give `['a','b','c','a','b','c','a']`.

Is there a built-in method to fill a pandas column (or numpy array) using a similar style of recycling?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With [`numpy.resize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) -

```
In [199]: a = ['a','b','c']

In [200]: np.resize(a,7)
Out[200]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 6):

Kinda, but it isn't as straightforward as it is in R.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
cyc = cycle(['a','b','c'])

pd.Series(list(islice(cyc, 0, 7)))

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    b
5    c
6    a
dtype: object
```

First, create an infinite iterator using `itertools.cycle`. Then, slice out a portion of this infinite iterator to retrieve just the number of elements you want, using `itertools.islice`.

Change `7` to as small or as large as you want your Series to be.

Comment: It's interesting that this isn't default behavior in pandas, but than again I've used pandas for almost 3 years and just now needed this functionality.  Thanks for drawing my attention back to `itertools`