# How to add a items from a list to a dataframe column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have list containing numbers `x =(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)`
I also have a **DataFrame** with 1000+ rows.
The thing I need is to assign the numbers in the list into a column/creating a new column, so that the rows 1-8 contain the numbers 1-8, but after that it starts again, so row 9 should contain number 1 and so on.

It seems really easy, but somehow I cannot manage to do this.

Comment: I think the thing you are looking for is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956686/recycling-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible ways (example here with 3 items to repeat):

##### with numpy.tile

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(10)})
x = (1,2,3)
df['newcol'] = np.tile(x, len(df)//len(x)+1)[:len(df)]
```

##### with `itertools`

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(10)})
x = (1,2,3)
df['newcol'] = list(islice(cycle(x), len(df
```

input:

```
   col
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
```

output:

```
   col  newcol
0    0       1
1    1       2
2    2       3
3    3       1
4    4       2
5    5       3
6    6       1
7    7       2
8    8       3
9    9       1
```

Comment: Tanks a lot, it worked ike a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import ceil
df['new_column'] = (x*(ceil(len(df)/len(x))))[:len(df)]
```